# после запуска бот выводит "выберите слово с правильным ударением ", я выбираю вариант, а дальше он ничего не отвечает

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('.....')
points = 0
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите /train, чтобы начать тренироваться \nВведите /start для перезапуска')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['train'])
def train(message):
    points = 0
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    word1 = types.KeyboardButton('аэропОрты')
    word2 = types.KeyboardButton('аэропортЫ')
    markup.add(word1, word2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите слово с правильным ударением:', reply_markup=markup)
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        # начинаем отслеживать 1 вопрос
        if message.text == word1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
            points +=1
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            word1 = types.KeyboardButton('бАнты')
            word2 = types.KeyboardButton('бантЫ')
            markup.add(word1, word2)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите слово с правильным ударением:', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == word2:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Неверно. Ваш счёт: {points}")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас эта проверка проходит `if message.chat.type == 'private':`?

Comment: именно на этом моменте код дальше не идет. я не понимаю, почему не проходит проверка(

Comment: Перед этим if добавьте `print(message.chat.type)` и посмотрите, чему оно равно. Скорее всего не **'private'**